# $f(A \cap f^{-1}(B))=f(A)\cap B$ An instance of more general phenomenon?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just realized that $f(A \cap f^{-1}(B))=f(A)\cap B$.

The one way was obvious: $f(A \cap f^{-1}(B)) \subset f(A) \cap f(f^{-1}(B)) \subset f(A) \cap B$.

The other way I had to think about for a minute.

Do you think about this fact as an instance of a general phenomenon, or is it more or less a "trick" you remember?

Comment: If $x\in A$ and $f(x)\in B$, then $x\in f^{-1}(B)$, so $x\in A\cap f^{-1}(B)$ and $f(x)\in f(A\cap f^{-1}(B)$. I think this is even easier than the other direction. Of course one has to assume that $f\colon X\to X$.

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry, $f:X \not\to X$; rather, $B$ is a subset of the codomain.

Comment: Oh, yes, the hypothesis $f\colon X\to X$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to argue for the "general phenomenon" interpretation. Begin by noting that

- a point $y$ belongs to $f(A)\cap f(B)$ iff its preimage $f^{-1}(p)$ meets both $A$ and $B$.
- a point $y$ belongs to $f(A\cap B)$ iff its preimage $f^{-1}(p)$ meets $A\cap B$.

In particular, $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$, and the inclusion is strict when some preimage  happens to hit both $A$ and $B$, but never at the same time. To pull off this trick, $f^{-1}(p)$ must meet $A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus A$.

A set $A$ is *saturated* if $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$. In English, this means that if $A$ intersects some point preimage $f^{-1}(p)$, then it contains all $f^{-1}(p)$. This rules out the scenario from the previous paragraph.

Conclusion: $f(A\cap B) = f(A)\cap f(B)$ holds provided that at least one of two sets is saturated.