# Is $f(A \cap f^{-1}(B))=f(A)\cap B$ an instance of more general phenomenon?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546970/fa-cap-f-1b-fa-cap-b-an-instance-of-more-general-phenomenon) question, I asked for a more general interpretation of the fact that $f(A \cap f^{-1}(B))=f(A)\cap B$, rather than it just being a "trick" that one remembers. (Here $f:X\to Y$, and $A\subset X$, $B\subset Y$.)

A user @user103254 responded with the helpful fact that a sufficient condition for $f(S\cap T) = f(S)\cap f(T)$ is that either $S$ or $T$ is saturated ("saturated" in this context means $f^{-1}(f(S))=S$).

First of all, I am curious whether we can find a necessary condition for $f(S \cap T)=f(S)\cap f(T)$, or a more strict sufficient condition.

But also, given the sufficient condition @user103254 mentions, how can we use this to demonstrate $f(A \cap f^{-1}(B))=f(A)\cap B$? We can start with $f(A \cap f^{-1}(B))=f(A) \cap f(f^{-1}(B))$, but then for equality, it seems we need the more specific argument I gave in the post I linked to.

**Edit:** I believe I have shown that, similarly, a sufficient condition for $f(S\setminus T)=f(S) \setminus f(T)$ is that $T$ is saturated.

**Edit 2:** To show that $f(A)\cap f(f^{-1}(B))=f(A)\cap B$, we can note that the elements in $B\setminus f(f^{-1}(B))$ are exactly those in $B\cap (Y\setminus f(X))$, so that takes care of how to show the given property. It remains to look for a necessary condition for $f(S \cap T)=f(S)\cap f(T)$, or a more strict sufficient condition

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67228/where-do-all-these-projection-formulas-come-from) for more examples (most of which are relatively sophisticated) and discussion.

Comment: Wow, indeed those are some sophisticated examples.